Are Point-Time Locked Contracts possible in Ethereum?
PTLCs have been discussed in Bitcoin as being a major improvement over HTLCs for atomic swaps. I have seen HTLCs in Solidity, but never PTLCs. This article says the following:

Cross-chain atomic swaps based on adaptor signatures, or at least semi-scriptless adaptor signature schemes designed for the ECDSA curve, are incompatible with Ethereum. This is because Ethereum uses the account model, not the UTXO model. Specifically, in adaptor signature-based atomic swaps, refund transactions must be pre-signed. However, in the Ethereum system, transactions cannot be pre-signed without knowing the nonce. Therefore, one party can send a transaction between the pre-signature and the transaction execution, invalidating the pre-signed transaction (because the nonce has been used and cannot be reused).

As I understand it, adaptor signatures are necessary for PTLCs to work (although PTLCs are not mentioned in the article), so does this mean that ethereum inherently will never support this kind of atomic swap?
